# 1: Task failed with an exception

Tags: java, android, kotlin

FAILURE: Build completed with 4 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Failed to transform jackson-core-2.15.2.jar (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.2) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\pc.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.15.2\a6fe1836469a69b3ff66037c324d75fc66ef137c\jackson-core-2.15.2.jar.
> > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\pc.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.15.2\a6fe1836469a69b3ff66037c324d75fc66ef137c\jackson-core-2.15.2.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: IllegalArgumentException, message: Unsupported class file major version 63. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
> Suggestions:
> - Check out existing issues at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:460323&s=modified_time:desc, it's possible that this issue has already been filed there.
> - If this issue has not been filed, please report it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460323 (run with --stacktrace and provide a stack trace if possible).

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform jackson-core-2.15.2.jar (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.2) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\pc.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.15.2\a6fe1836469a69b3ff66037c324d75fc66ef137c\jackson-core-2.15.2.jar.
> > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\pc.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.15.2\a6fe1836469a69b3ff66037c324d75fc66ef137c\jackson-core-2.15.2.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: IllegalArgumentException, message: Unsupported class file major version 63. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
> Suggestions:
> - Check out existing issues at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:460323&s=modified_time:desc, it's possible that this issue has already been filed there.
> - If this issue has not been filed, please report it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460323 (run with --stacktrace and provide a stack trace if possible).

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 3: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform jackson-core-2.15.2.jar (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.2) to match attributes {artifactType=android-jni, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\pc.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.15.2\a6fe1836469a69b3ff66037c324d75fc66ef137c\jackson-core-2.15.2.jar.
> > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\pc.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.15.2\a6fe1836469a69b3ff66037c324d75fc66ef137c\jackson-core-2.15.2.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: IllegalArgumentException, message: Unsupported class file major version 63. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
> Suggestions:
> - Check out existing issues at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:460323&s=modified_time:desc, it's possible that this issue has already been filed there.
> - If this issue has not been filed, please report it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460323 (run with --stacktrace and provide a stack trace if possible).

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 4: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAndroidTestDuplicateClasses'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform jackson-core-2.15.2.jar (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.2) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\pc.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.15.2\a6fe1836469a69b3ff66037c324d75fc66ef137c\jackson-core-2.15.2.jar.
> > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\pc.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.15.2\a6fe1836469a69b3ff66037c324d75fc66ef137c\jackson-core-2.15.2.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: IllegalArgumentException, message: Unsupported class file major version 63. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
> Suggestions:
> - Check out existing issues at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:460323&s=modified_time:desc, it's possible that this issue has already been filed there.
> - If this issue has not been filed, please report it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460323 (run with --stacktrace and provide a stack trace if possible).

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

```
          .
```

Comment: Welcome! StackOverflow is a question and answer site. It would be great if you could update your post to let us know what your question is. Assuming it's about how to fix these build errors, can you also share more information about what you were doing that caused the error, and what you've tried so far when attempting to fix it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.